# Различия бинарного кода с/с++

Tags: c++, c

Например есть программа полностью написанная на ANSI C, если мы ее соберем компилятором С как первый вариант а во втором варианте соберем компилятором C++. Будут ли различия в собранном файле? Т.е. можно ли писать код для систем которые требуют программ написанных на С а затем собирать их с помощью C++ без побочных эффектов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут предыдущие ораторы описали некоторые различия языков С и С++, я же постараюсь ответить на вопрос :)

> Будут ли различия в собранном файле?

Безусловно, будут. И вы сами можете легко в этом убедиться с помощью утилиты `diff`, например (если натравить ее на два соответствующих бинарных файла, полученных от компиляторов С и С++). Да и достаточно просто сравнить размеры - они будут немного разные.

Еще один способ увидеть различия - ключик `-S` у компилятора gcc.
Если с этим ключом скомпилировать исходник:

```
g++ -S main.c   # компилятор С++
gсс -S main.c   # компилятор С
```

то в той же директории появится файл с расширением `.s` - ассемблерный листинг вашего кода. Сравнение этого листинга для случаев gcc и g++ подводит к некоторому ответу на второй вопрос:

> можно ли писать код для систем которые требуют программ написанных на С а затем собирать их с помощью C++ без побочных эффектов?

Во многих случаях ответ будет - да, можно. Если код написан на ANSI C, совместимом с подмножеством языка С++, то сгенерированный ассемблерный код будет (почти) одинаков для случаев gcc и g++. Он будет различаться только некоторой обвязкой (g++ добавит инициализацию своих stream'ов и т.п.). Названия функций тоже будут разные, но это не имеет значения, поскольку в бинарнике будут адреса, а не имена.

Comment: а различие в `sizeof('a')` вы считаете несущественным?

Comment: @VladD, нет ни одного отличия С от С++, которое я бы считал несущественным :). Просто, мне показалось, автор вопроса не совсем об этом спрашивал.

Comment: Просто вы пишете «Если код написан на ANSI C, совместимом с подмножеством языка С++...»

Answer (score 3):

С++  и C - это два разных языка, у которых даже внешне одинаковые конструкции имеют разную семантику.

Например, в C++ вы можете написать

```
int x;
int y = 10;

( x = y ) += 20;
```

В C у вас такой код компилироваться не будет.

Даже обычное всем знакомое "классическое"`for`-предложение и то имеет различие в определении.

И уж совсем тривиальное отличии: в C строковые литералы имеют типы неконстантных символьных массивов, а в C++ - константных символьных массивов.

Кроме того в C в отличии от C++ объявления не являются предложениями языка.

Об этом конкретном различии я писал на своем [персональном форуме](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000050-000-0-0-1412969191).

В языке C присутствуют составные литералы и массивы переменной длины, которые отсутствуют в C++.

С другой стороны, например, в C++ есть ссылки, которые отсутствуют в C.

Если вы пишите на C, например,

```
int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
```

, как часто советуют некоторые программисты в том числе и на Stackoverflow и подобным советам дают запредельные положительные баллы, то вам может не хватить всей вашей жизни, чтобы в вашем проекте, который вы захотите откомпилировать, как C++ проект, поменять все подобные предложения на

```
int *p = ( int * )malloc( sizeof( int ) );
```

С другой стороны, это хорошая идея попробовать скомпилировать вашу программу на C, как программу на C++, потому что компилятор на C++ может обратить ваше внимание на те вещи, которые компилятор на C проглотит, не замечая, но тем не менее данный код не является удовлетворительным.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, C и C++ — разные языки, различие между ними даже не в кодогенерации, а в семантике.

Простейший пример — `sizeof('a')` даёт разные результаты в разных языках.

Кроме того, name mangling в C++ обычно даёт другие имена функций на уровне бинарного API.

Comment: Стандарт С++ гарантирует, что размер char-а - один байт. Вы хотите сказать, что стандарт C этого не гарантирует? :))

Comment: @Arkady по стандарту C++, `'a'` является символьным литералом типа `char`. По стандарту С, `'a'` является символьным литералом типа `int`. Поэтому `sizeof('a') == sizeof(char)` является прекрасным тестом на C++ vs C.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry спасибо, не знал)